# Anybody know any resources for adding your own language to visual studio 2010 that is not managed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

I've seen the MyC pages in code project and MS's Iron Python. Is there a simple sample for unmanaged code? I'd like to add a superset to C++.

**Update**
Eventually the code may not be convertible to C++ and so I would like to find a start to finish example of creating an unmanaged new language for VS including IDE support, brace matching, etc. Think D or the the concepts project at Indiana State.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "adding your own language"? You can specify a Custom Build Tool and associate it with a file extensions, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I can write a command line compiler that does what I want, but I'd like it to be usable inside VS for ease of use. If I understand Custom Build Tools, they are on a file by file basis rather than whole project. I need to manipulate the entire project before any C++ gets processed. It's kind of like whole project optimization after the files are compiled, I need whole project pre-processor. If build tools do that, then great. Oh, and I need to know what has and has not been processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio extensions are usually (at least for nontrivial extensions) implemented as packages by deriving from the [`Package`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb161924.aspx) class from the SDK.  Your package class is responsible for defining all of the capabilities that it provides.

You will need to implement a [language service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165099.aspx) for IntelliSense, autocompletion, syntax highlighting, brace matching, and other language-specific source editing capabilities.

If you have custom tools that you want to use at build, you can write your own [custom tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx) usable by MSBuild.

There are a lot of pieces required to extend Visual Studio to support a whole new language, though the amount of work depends on what features you really want to provide and how much existing functionality you can reuse.

The [Visual Studio SDK documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx) is the best place to go for information.

Comment: I do not know of any such walkthrough, sorry. However, there are numerous walkthroughs in the Visual Studio SDK documentation to which I linked that guide you through creating each piece (e.g., creating a basic package, implementing the scanner and parser interfaces, etc.).